# I am learning to make a website usign nodejs, express, mongoose, handlebars. trouble deleting a reply to a comment on a webpage

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mongoose, handlebars.js

I am learning to create a website that allows users to post blogs, to comment on blogs and to reply to those comments. I have used replies[this] in the comment schema to deal with replies to comments. But I am having trouble being able to allow the user to delete these replies. Here is my server side code to delete comments and replies:

```
// Submit form to leave comment or reply
app.post('/leaveComment/:id', requireLogin, uploadImage.single('commentImage'), async (req, res) => {
    try {

        const { commentId } = req.query;  // Extract commentId from query parameters
        const post = await Post.findById({_id: req.params.id});
        const commentImage = req.file ? `https://s3.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/${req.file.originalname}` : null;

        const newComment = {
            commentUser: req.user, // Use the user object directly
            commentBody: req.body.commentBody,
            commentImage: commentImage,
            dateCreated: new Date()
        };
        if (!newComment.commentBody || newComment.commentBody.trim() === '') {
            // Comment body is empty or contains only whitespace
            return res.redirect(`/fullPost/${post._id}`);
        }


        if (commentId) {  // If a commentId exists, it's a reply
            const comment = post.comments.id(commentId);
            comment.replies.push(newComment);
        } else {  // It's a top-level comment
            post.comments.push(newComment);
        }

        await post.save();
        res.redirect(`/fullPost/${post._id}`);
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
        res.status(500).send("An error occurred");
    }
});

// Delete a specific comment or reply
app.get('/deleteComment/:postId/:commentId', requireLogin, async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const currentUser = req.user; 
        const { replyId } = req.query; 
        const foundPost = await Post.findById(req.params.postId);
        
        if (replyId) {  // If it's a reply
            const comment = foundPost.comments.id(req.params.commentId);
            const reply = comment.replies.id(replyId);
            
            // Check if the user is the author of the reply
            if (reply.commentUser.toString() !== currentUser._id.toString()) {
                return res.status(403).send('Permission denied: You can only delete your own replies.');
            }

            reply.remove();
        } else {  // It's a top-level comment
            const comment = foundPost.comments.id(req.params.commentId);

            // Check if the user is the author of the comment
            if (comment.commentUser.toString() !== req.user._id.toString()) {
                return res.status(403).send('Permission denied: You can only delete your own comments.');
            }

        
            comment.remove();
        }
        
        await foundPost.save();
        res.status(200).send('Deleted successfully');
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
        res.status(500).send("An error occurred");
    }
});
```

Here is my front end,

```
        <head>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/emoji-mart@latest/dist/browser.js"></script>
</head>
{{#if successMessage}}
<div class="alert alert-success">
  {{successMessage}}
</div>
{{/if}}

<div class="media">
  <a href="/userProfile/{{post.postUser._id}}">
    <img src="{{post.postUser.image}}" class="mr-3" width="64px" alt="">
    <span>{{post.postUser.fullname}}</span>
  </a>
  <div class="media-body">
    <h5 class="mt-0">{{post.title}} <small><i class="{{post.icon}}"></i></small></h5>
    <img src="{{post.image}}" alt="" width="300" height="auto">
    <p>{{post.body}}</p>
    <img src="{{image}}" class="mr-3 responsive-img" alt="">
    <br>
    <small>{{getLastMoment dateCreated 'MMM Do YYYY, h:mm:ss a'}}</small>
     
    <div class="comment-and-form" style="display: flex; align-items: center;"></div>
    
     <a href="#" id="comment-icon" onclick="toggleCommentForm('comment_form')">
  <i class="fa-solid fa-comment"></i> 
</a>

      <a href="/deletePost/{{post._id}}"><i class="fa fa-trash post-icons"></i></a>&nbsp &nbsp</a> 
    </h4>

    <form id="comment_form" action="/leaveComment/{{post._id}}" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="form-inline" style="display:none; margin-left: 20px;">
      
      <div class="form-group mx-sm-2 mg-2">
         <textarea type="text" name="commentBody" id="commentBody1"  class="form-control emoji-input" placeholder="Leave Comment..." rows="4" cols="50" maxlength="1000"></textarea>
        <span id="charCount1">0/1000</span>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning" id="emoji-picker-btn-new1"></button>
    
      </div>

      <br>
      <div class="form-group mx-sm-2 mg-2">
        <input type="file" name="commentImage" id="commentImage" class="form-control-file" placeholder="Leave Comment">
      </div>
      &nbsp <button class="btn btn-primary mb-2 mt-2" type="submit">
        <i class="fa-brands fa-telegram"></i> Post
      </button>
    </form>
    <hr>
    {{#each post.comments}}
    <div class="media mt-3">
      <a class="mr-3" href="/userProfile/{{commentUser._id}}">
        <img src="{{commentUser.image}}" class="mr-3" width="64px"  alt="">
        <span>{{commentUser.fullname}}</span>
      </a>
      
      <div class="media-body">
        <p id="comment-body-{{_id}}">{{commentBody}}</p>
       
        <form id="edit-comment-form-{{_id}}" action="#" method="POST" style="display:none">
          <textarea name="newCommentBody" id="newCommentBody-{{_id}}" class="form-control emoji-input"   rows="4" cols="50" maxlength="1000">{{commentBody}}</textarea>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning" id="emoji-picker-btn-{{_id}}"></button>
          <button type="button" onclick="submitEditComment('{{../post._id}}', '{{_id}}')">Save</button>
          <span id="charCount">0/1000</span>
        </form>
      
        {{#if commentImage}}
        <img src="{{commentImage}}" alt="User uploaded image" width="200" height="auto">
        {{/if}}
        <br>
        <small data-comment-date-{{_id}}="{{getLastMoment dateCreated 'x'}}">{{getLastMoment dateCreated 'MMM Do YYYY, h:mm:ss a'}}</small>
       
      
          {{#if commentUser}}
           &nbsp
         &nbsp&nbsp
      <a href="/editComment/{{post._id}}/{{comment._id}}" class="edit-button" onclick="showEditForm(event,'{{_id}}','data-comment-date-{{_id}}')">
  <i class="fa fa-pencil post-icons"></i>
</a>

       &nbsp
      &nbsp
     <a href="#" onclick="deleteComment('{{../post._id}}', '{{_id}}')"><i class="fa fa-trash post-icons"></i></a>
{{/if}}
      
        <!-- Reply button -->
    <a href="#" onclick="toggleReplyForm('{{_id}}', '{{../post._id}}')">&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbspReply</a>

    <!-- Reply form -->
    <form id="reply-form-{{_id}}" action="/leaveComment/{{../post._id}}?commentId={{_id}}" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" style="display: none;">
   <textarea type="text" name="commentBody" id="replycommentBody"  class="form-control emoji-input" placeholder="Leave Comment..." rows="4" cols="50" maxlength="1000"></textarea>
        <span id="replycharCount">0/1000</span>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning" id="emoji-picker-btn-reply"></button>
       <button class="btn btn-primary mb-2 mt-2" type="submit">
        <i class="fa-brands fa-telegram"></i> Post
      </button>
    </form>

 <div class="expand-replies">
    <!-- Expand/Collapse button for replies -->
    <a href="#" onclick="toggleReplies('{{_id}}')">Expand Replies</a>
    <hr>
</div>



  </div>
</div>


 <div id="replies-container-{{_id}}" style="display: none;" class="replies-container">
  {{#each replies}}
    <div class="media mt-3">
      <a class="mr-3" href="/userProfile/{{commentUser._id}}">
       <img src="{{commentUser.image}}" class="mr-3 user-image" alt="user profile">
        <span>{{commentUser.fullname}}</span>
      
        
      </a>
      <div class="media-body">
        <p id="comment-body-{{_id}}">{{commentBody}}</p>
       
        
        {{#if commentImage}}
         <img src="{{commentUser.image}}" class="mr-3 user-image" alt="user image">
          
        {{/if}}
        
        <br>
        <small data-comment-date-{{_id}}="{{getLastMoment dateCreated 'x'}}">{{getLastMoment dateCreated 'MMM Do YYYY, h:mm:ss a'}}</small>
       

       
          
          
          &nbsp
          &nbsp
        <a href="#" onclick="deleteReply('{{../post._id}}', '{{_id}}', '{{replyId}}')">
     <i class="fa fa-trash post-icons"></i>
 </a>
   
      
      
      </div>
    </div>
    <hr>
  {{/each}}
</div>
       
      </div>
    </div>
    <hr>
    {{/each}}
    {{#if post.allowComments}}
    <form id="comment_form" action="/leaveComment/{{post._id}}" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="form-inline" style="display:none">
      <div class="form-group mx-sm-2 mg-2">
       
        <textarea type="text" name="commentBody" id="commentBody2" class="form-control emoji-input" placeholder="Leave Comment..." rows="4" cols="50" maxlength="1000"></textarea>
        <span id="charCount2">0/1000</span>
         <button type="bu
oup mx-sm-2 mg-2">
        <input type="file" name="commentImage" id="commentImage" class="form-control-file">
      </div>
      <button class="btn btn-primary mb-2 mt-2" type="submit">
        <i class="fa fa-comment"></i>
      </button>
    </form>



    <script>
  let isPickerOpen = false; // Track whether the emoji picker is open
  
  
  function toggleCommentForm(formId) {
  const commentForm = document.getElementById(formId);

  if (commentForm.style.display === 'none' || commentForm.style.display === '') {
    // Comment form is closed or not set, so open it
    commentForm.style.display = 'block';
  } else {
    // Comment form is open, so close it
    commentForm.style.display = 'none';
  }
}

  
 function showEditForm(event, commentId, dateAttribute) {
    event.preventDefault();
    const FIFTEEN_MINUTES = 15 * 60 * 1000;
    const commentDateElement = document.querySelector(`[data-comment-date-${commentId}]`);
    const commentDate = parseInt(commentDateElement.getAttribute(`data-comment-date-${commentId}`), 10);
    const now = new Date().getTime();
    const timeDifference = now - commentDate;
    if (timeDifference > FIFTEEN_MINUTES) {
      alert('Time limit exceeded, you cannot edit your comment.');
      return;
    }
    document.getElementById('comment-body-' + commentId).style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById('edit-comment-form-' + commentId).style.display = 'block';
    document.getElementById(`emoji-picker-btn-${commentId}`).addEventListener('click', function() {
      toggleEmojiPicker(`newCommentBody-${commentId}`, `charCount-${commentId}`);
    });
  }


function submitEditComment(postId, commentId) {
    const newCommentBody = document.getElementById(`newCommentBody-${commentId}`).value;
    const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('POST', `/editComment/${postId}/${commentId}`, true);
    xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xhr.readyState === 4) {
            if (xhr.status === 200) {
                location.reload(); // Reload the page for a successful edit
            } else if (xhr.status === 403) {
                // Permission denied, display an error message
                alert('Permission denied: You can only edit your own comments.');
            } else {
                // Handle other error cases and display appropriate messages
                alert('An error occurred while editing the comment.');
            }
        }
    };
    xhr.send(`commentBody=${encodeURIComponent(newCommentBody)}`);
}



  function deleteComment(postId, commentId) {
    const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('GET', `/deleteComment/${postId}/${commentId}`, true);
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (xhr.readyState === 4) {
            if (xhr.status === 200) {
                location.reload(); // Reload the page for successful deletion
            } else if (xhr.status === 403) {
                // Permission denied, display an error message
                alert('Permission denied: You can only delete your own comments.');
            } else {
                // Handle other error cases and display appropriate messages
                alert('An error occurred while deleting the comment.');
            }
        }
    };
    xhr.send();
}




 function toggleEmojiPicker(inputId, charCountId) {
  if (isPickerOpen) {
    const existingPicker = document.getElementById('emoji-picker');
    if (existingPicker) {
      existingPicker.remove();
    }
    isPickerOpen = false;
  } else {
    const pickerOptions = {
      onEmojiSelect: function(emoji) {
        const emojiInput = document.getElementById(inputId);
        emojiInput.value += emoji.native;
        const charCountSpan = document.getElementById(charCountId);
        charCountSpan.innerText = `${emojiInput.value.length}/1000`;
      }
    };
    const picker = new EmojiMart.Picker(pickerOptions);
    picker.id = 'emoji-picker';
    picker.style.position = 'fixed';
    picker.style.bottom = '0px';
    picker.style.left = '0px';
    document.body.appendChild(picker);
    isPickerOpen = true;

    // Make the picker draggable
    let isDragging = false;
    let offsetX, offsetY;

    picker.addEventListener('mousedown', function(event) {
      isDragging = true;
      offsetX = event.clientX - picker.getBoundingClientRect().left;
      offsetY = event.clientY - picker.getBoundingClientRect().top;
    });

    window.addEventListener('mousemove', function(event) {
      if (isDragging) {
        const x = event.clientX - offsetX;
        const y = event.clientY - offsetY;
        picker.style.left = x + 'px';
        picker.style.top = y + 'px';
        picker.style.bottom = 'auto';  // Reset 'bottom' to allow 'top' to take effect
      }
    });

    window.addEventListener('mouseup', function() {
      isDragging = false;
    });
  }
}
function initializeTextareaAndCharCount(textareaId, charCountId) {
  const textarea = document.getElementById(textareaId);
  const charCountSpan = document.getElementById(charCountId);

  textarea.addEventListener('input', function() {
    const charCount = this.value.length;
    charCountSpan.innerText = `${charCount}/1000`;
  });
}





initializeTextareaAndCharCount('replycommentBody', 'replycharCount');
document.getElementById('emoji-picker-btn-reply').addEventListener('click', function() {
  toggleEmojiPicker('replycommentBody', 'replycharCount');
});



initializeTextareaAndCharCount('commentBody1', 'charCount1');
document.getElementById('emoji-picker-btn-new1').addEventListener('click', function() {
  toggleEmojiPicker('commentBody1', 'charCount1');
});
initializeTextareaAndCharCount('commentBody2', 'charCount2');
document.getElementById('emoji-picker-btn-new2').addEventListener('click', function() {
  toggleEmojiPicker('commentBody2', 'charCount2');
});





// Function to toggle the reply form for a comment
  function toggleReplyForm(commentId, postId) {
    event.preventDefault();
    const replyForm = document.getElementById(`reply-form-${commentId}`);
    replyForm.style.display = replyForm.style.display === 'none' ? 'block' : 'none';
  }

  // Function to toggle the visibility of replies
  function toggleReplies(commentId) {
    event.preventDefault();
    const repliesContainer = document.getElementById(`replies-container-${commentId}`);
    repliesContainer.style.display = repliesContainer.style.display         === 'none' ? 'block' : 'none';
     }







    </script>

    
    
 
    {{else}}
    <p class="red"> Comments are not allowed </p>
    {{/if}}
    </div>
    </div>
```

Every time I try to delete a reply, I get a 404 error. I can delete comments, it's just replies. I have tried numerous things like changing routes and functions to include replyId but it just keeps giving the 404 error. Any ideas why it's not working?

Comment: Narrow down your question: it can't be about express _and_ mongoose _and_ handlebars, which part is going wrong (and that'll require a bit of debugging on your end, probably involving reducing your code to [mcve] form), and then specifically ask about that.

Comment: How does your `reply.remove();` function work?

Comment: This is how it should work, I find a post from its id, using Post.findById(req.params.postId), I find a comment subdocument in post by its id using foundPost.comments.id(req.params.commentId), then replies are found by finding subdocument in the comment using comment.replies.id(replyId). That gives me reference to the reply, then I remove it with call .remove(). Then I save the parent document (foundPost).

Answer (score 0):

- List item

Here is what I can tell you from the code snippets you provided:

Deleting a comment in this route works because `/deleteComment/:postId/:commentId` receives `postId` and `commentId`, which are the only two parameters needed to delete a comment. When you try to delete a reply, your server-side code does not receive the needed `replyId`, hence the 404.

Also, when you have a GET route it needs to be matched exactly on both the front end and the back end in order for it to work. This is why having two GET request will solve your problem. One to delete comments `/deleteComment/:postId/:commentId`, and one to delete replies `/deleteReply/:postId/:commentId/:replyId`.

There are multiple ways to go about it. Here is one approach.

Server-side:

```
app.get('/deleteComment/:postId/:commentId', requireLogin, async (req, res) => {
  try {
      const currentUser = req.user; 
      const foundPost = await Post.findById(req.params.postId);
  
      const comment = foundPost.comments.id(req.params.commentId);

      if(!comment) {
          return res.status(404).send('Comment not found');
      }

      // Check if the user is the author of the comment
      if (comment.commentUser.toString() !== currentUser._id.toString()) {
          return res.status(403).send('Permission denied: You can only delete your own comments.');
      }

      comment.remove();
      
      await foundPost.save();
      res.status(200).send('Deleted successfully');
  } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
      res.status(500).send("An error occurred");
  }
});

app.get('/deleteReply/:postId/:commentId/:replyId', requireLogin, async (req, res) => {
  try {
      const currentUser = req.user; 
      const foundPost = await Post.findById(req.params.postId);
      

      const comment = foundPost.comments.id(req.params.commentId);
      const reply = comment.replies.id(req.params.replyId);

      if(!reply) {
          return res.status(404).send('Reply not found');
      }
      
      // Check if the user is the author of the reply
      if (reply.commentUser.toString() !== currentUser._id.toString()) {
          return res.status(403).send('Permission denied: You can only delete your own replies.');
      }

      reply.remove();
      
      await foundPost.save();
      res.status(200).send('Deleted successfully');
  } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
      res.status(500).send("An error occurred");
  }
});
```

Front end:

```
function deleteReply(postId, commentId, replyId) {
  const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.open('GET', `/deleteReply/${postId}/${commentId}/${replyId}`, true);
  xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
      if (xhr.readyState === 4) {
          if (xhr.status === 200) {
              location.reload(); 
          } else if (xhr.status === 403) {
             
              alert('Permission denied: You can only delete your own reply.');
          } else {
             
              alert('An error occurred while deleting the reply.');
          }
      }
  };
  xhr.send();
}

  function deleteComment(postId, commentId) {
    const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('GET', `/deleteComment/${postId}/${commentId}`, true);
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (xhr.readyState === 4) {
            if (xhr.status === 200) {
                location.reload(); 
            } else if (xhr.status === 403) {
               
                alert('Permission denied: You can only delete your own comments.');
            } else {
               
                alert('An error occurred while deleting the comment.');
            }
        }
    };
    xhr.send();
}
```

Now make sure that you use two different anchors one delete a reply and one to delete a post:

Delete Comment:

```
 <a href="#" onclick="deleteComment('{{../post._id}}', '{{_id}}')">
     <i class="fa fa-trash post-icons"></i>
 </a>
```

Delete Reply ( make sure to use the proper variable for replyId )

```
 <a href="#" onclick="deleteReply('{{../post._id}}', '{{_id}}', '{{replyId}}')">
     <i class="fa fa-trash post-icons"></i>
 </a>
```

Again, you are facing the 404 error, because `rpleyId` is undefined in your current code, because it is not part of the URL query.

It is also good practice, when you are using a route to delete something to use a DELETE route.

Lmk if you need more help, I would be happy to help :)

Comment: Are you sure that `req.body` works without any dependence?

Comment: I tried you solution before, as soon as I add replyId into the route, then I can not delete comments anymore, and still cannot delete replies. If I remove repyId from backend route and front end java script. I can delete comments no problem. I think this is a handlebars issue. Here is the debugging errors from the web console, 404 error.
Post ID: <empty string> 650aae045cf1daeeb910bd58:370:13
Comment ID: <empty string> 650aae045cf1daeeb910bd58:371:13
Reply ID: <empty string> 650aae045cf1daeeb910bd58:372:13
replyId is empty 650aae045cf1daeeb910bd58:374:13

Comment: I updated my comment to show you how to tackle the problem with 2 get requests.

Comment: I try that before and it givesGEThttp://localhost:3000/deleteComment//
[HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found 68ms]

and it does the same with your two routes for delete.

Comment: In the code above, the two routes have different names:`/deleteComment/:postId/:commented` and 
`/deleteReply/:postId/:commentId/:replyId`. Try to copy and paste the code I provided. Also, if you are using GitHub, share a link to your repository and I will be able to reproduce your code and help better.

Comment: I added more code on how a comment/reply is submitted and more front end how they are incorporated into handlebars. Thanks for trying to find a solution for this.